# Lines of CSS only being delivered while logged in

Tags: css, admin-css

I am working on a clients site and I noticed a few lines of CSS are only being delivered while logged in to the WP Dashboard. Any idea what might cause this discrepancy?

Comment: There's probably not enough information in your question to answer it specifically.  However, it very well could be a plugin.  Try deactivating plugins to see if it's still there.  If not, you can reactivate plugins one-by-one to determine which one.

Comment: Thank you butlerblog for the response, it was in fact a conflict with a plugin!